# DBNull Exception from datatable row

Tags: vb.net

I am a beginner and stuck at one place. So basically I need to set date value to one of the datarow. But when ever date is empty string I need to set it to "Now". But I am not able to do so.
I am getting exception as `System.Data.StrongTypingException' "The value for column 'dteEntry' in table is DBNull`

Here is what I have

```
    Dim strTimeStamp as String = "" ' code taken out for brevity
' dteEntry is of Date datatype
Dim newRow As ABC.Dataset.dtCardRow = ret.NewdtCardRow()
    If (Date.TryParse(strTimeStamp, newRow.dteEntry)) Then

    else
    newRow.dteEntry = Now
    End If
```

Comment: This question lacks detail for a good answer. What is `.strTimeStamp` and what is `newRow.dteEntry`...

Comment: ...also Strings are not dates.  Other tips omitted for brevity.

Comment: made some edits.

Comment: @Codexer: newRow is basically a datarow for a table.

Comment: No this does not work. To be honest, everything is working fine Syntax wise and all. Only problem is when empty string comes I get the exception.

Comment: `If (Date.TryParse(strTimeStamp, newRow.dteEntry))` this line works perfectly fine for other cases, only fails when empty string comes

Comment: We cant know what all was omitted for brevity, but there is rarely a good reason to created a "date string" only to parse it into a date.  Is the db column date or string?  Also, as posted I dont think that will compile and it obviously is not simply copy-pasted from the IDE.

Comment: @Plutonix: The dteEntry is of `Date` datatype

Comment: You could try set the property "Nullvalue" of dteEntry column to empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strongly typed DataSet which auto generates code like the `NewdtCardRow` method that you have used above. Every property that is nullable has also a method to check if it's null, it's name is derived from the name of the property, something like `IsEntryDate_Null`, which you can use to check if the value is NULL. Otherwise you get an exception if you read that property as you do in `Date.TryParse`.

But in this case you can prevent this exception by using a local variable for `Date.Parse` instead of passing the property itself:

```
newRow.dteEntry = DateTime.Now ' writing doesnt cause this exception
Dim entryDate As Date
If Date.TryParse(strTimeStamp, entryDate) Then 
   newRow.dteEntry = entryDate ' writing doesnt cause this exception
End If
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I am beginner. Actually, I do have a property to check NULL for the datarow column. Can you kindly tell me if I was suppose to go that way. How to go about it. Suppose I don't want to create extra variable.

Comment: Can you put one small snippet which uses NULL auto generated property of the datarow column